# gradient of $\operatorname{tr}((AX)^2)$ w.r.t

Tags: matrices, derivatives, solution-verification, matrix-calculus, trace

For Hermitian matrices $A$ and $X$, I'm wondering how to calculate $\frac{\partial \operatorname{tr}(AXAX)}{\partial X}$.

My attempt:

Let $f(X) \mapsto \operatorname{tr}(AXAX)$. Expanding $f(X+H) = \operatorname{tr}(AXAX) + 2\operatorname{tr}(AXAH) + \operatorname{tr}(AHAH)$. Since the second term is $\operatorname{tr}((2AXA)^\dagger H)$ corresponds to the inner product of the gradient and $H$, the gradient seems to be $2AXA$. Is this a right approach?

Comment: It seems correct to me.

Comment: I would start with $B=AX$ for which $d\mathrm{tr}(BB)=2\mathrm{tr}B dB$. Then $dB=A \otimes I dX$ (remember that the derivative of a matrix w.r.t a matrix is a 4th order tensor).

Answer (score 1):

Let $M=AX,\,$ then applying the following formula from the Matrix Cookbook
$$\eqalign{
{d\operatorname{Tr}(M^k)} = (kM^{k-1})^T:dM \\
}$$
for $k=2\,$ and $\,dM=A\,dX\;$ yields
$$\eqalign{
{d\operatorname{Tr}(M^2)} &= 2M^T:A\,dX \;=\; 2A^TM^T:dX \\
\frac{\partial \operatorname{Tr}(M^2)}{\partial X}
  &= 2A^TM^T \;=\; 2(AXA)^T \\
}$$
...or the transpose of this, depending on
your preferred **layout convention**.